# Why my auto-indentation emacs script doesn't work on .cu files

Tags: emacs, lisp

I've just started to learn emacs. I used [this Lisp script](http://www.cslab.pepperdine.edu/warford/BatchIndentationEmacs.html) to indent my c++ code in batch, but strangely it doesn't work on .cu files **unless I rename %.cu to %.cpp**. Why? Is there any emacs variables I need to explicitly set in .emacs to make the formatting rules apply to .cu files? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `auto-mode-alist` contains information about which major mode files should be opened in.

You could, for example, use the following:

```
(add-to-list auto-mode-alist '("\\.cu\\'" . 'c++-mode))
```

Comment: Thanks @Lindydancer, the syntax highlighting works now, but the .cu files are still unable to be auto-indented, because "Buffer Kernel.cu is not a CC Mode buffer (c-set-style)".

Answer (score 1):

Changing the auto-mode-alist is the best solution for all *.cu files, but for adhoc modes you can put on the first line `-*-mode-*-` as in //`-*-c++-*-` and that works per file.